# There is Error: java: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation no exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

my programme use java and springboot and gradle technology，I have configure java environment and gradle,I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. when I build my programme there is always a problem like this:
**Error:(3, 40) java: package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation not exist**.
I have configure in my build.gradle like this:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

to download jar package but it's useless.
Thanks in advance

Comment: how does the whole gradle file look like?

Comment: Since there are **no dependencies** listed in that Gradle file, why on earth would you believe that it downloaded and added the Jackson library to your project? I highly recommend you **learn how to use Gradle** before asking any more questions on the topic. Any Gradle tutorial will cover *dependencies*, since that is a core part of what Gradle does.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you didn't add json serializers into your application.

Please add the [following dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json) to fix this (however usually it is arrived as dependency of Spring Boot Web or something).

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-json', version: '2.3.1.RELEASE'
```